# Sqoop incremental import and update does not work

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

How can I update the data in HDFS file similar to data in MySQL table? 
I checked the internet, but all the examples given are with *--incremental lastmodified* example.

Where in my case my MySQL table does not contain a date or timestamp column.
How can I update the data in HDFS file similar to data in MySQL table that does not contain date column?

I have MySQL table as below

```
mysql> select * from employee;
+----+--------+--------+------+-------+-----------+
| id | name   | gender | age  | state | language  |
+----+--------+--------+------+-------+-----------+
|  1 | user1  | m      |   25 | tn    | tamil     |
|  2 | user2  | m      |   41 | ka    | tamil     |
|  3 | user3  | f      |   47 | kl    | tamil     |
|  4 | user4  | f      |   52 | ap    | telugu    |
|  5 | user5  | m      |   55 | ap    | telugu    |
|  6 | user6  | f      |   43 | tn    | tamil     |
|  7 | user7  | m      |   34 | tn    | malayalam |
|  8 | user8  | f      |   33 | ap    | telugu    |
|  9 | user9  | m      |   36 | ap    | telugu    |
```

I imported to HDFS using the below command.

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase --username root --table employee --as-textfile --target-dir hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/cloudera/data/employee
```

The data is imported as expected.

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/cloudera/data/employee/
Found 6 items
-rw-r--r--   3 cloudera cloudera          0 2017-08-16 23:57 /user/cloudera/data/employee/_SUCCESS
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera cloudera          0 2017-08-16 23:56 /user/cloudera/data/employee/_logs
-rw-r--r--   3 cloudera cloudera        112 2017-08-16 23:56 /user/cloudera/data/employee/part-m-00000
-rw-r--r--   3 cloudera cloudera        118 2017-08-16 23:56 /user/cloudera/data/employee/part-m-00001
-rw-r--r--   3 cloudera cloudera        132 2017-08-16 23:56 /user/cloudera/data/employee/part-m-00002
-rw-r--r--   3 cloudera cloudera        136 2017-08-16 23:56 /user/cloudera/data/employee/part-m-00003
```

Now I updated values and inserted values in mysql table. But this table doesnot contain date column.

```
mysql> update employee set language = 'marathi' where id >= 8;
mysql> insert into employee (name,gender,age,state,language from people) values('user11','f','25','kl','malayalam');
```

I know the newly inserted values can be inserted to hdfs using --check-column, incremental append and --last-value.

But how can I update the values in hdfs for the mysql table rows 8 and 9 that were updated to 'marathi'? Also, my employee table does not contain a date or timestamp column.

Answer (score 1):

For newly inserted row, you can always use:

`--incremental append --check-column id --last-value 9`

But for getting updates from table not having updated_at column, I don't think thats possible. If your table is very small, then probably just do a full dump every time.

Or if you somehow can maintain track of what all ids got updated since last import, then let's say you know ids `7, 3, 4 and 8` got updated since last import, you can use the minimum of updated ids and use as `--last-value`. So your config will be:

`--incremental append --check-column id --last-value 3 --merge-key id`

where `--merge-key id` will tell sqoop to `merge` the new incremental data with old based on `id` column.